# How do I pass AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY to docker run within a Makefile?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, makefile, boto3

I have defined my config and credentials inside `~/.aws/` as usual.

In my python script running inside Docker, to get `boto3` to detect the credentials I run

```bash
docker run -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY my_app_name
```

Success!

But, in a Makefile (kindly provided by https://gist.github.com/mpneuried/0594963ad38e68917ef189b4e6a269db), I have the following:

```
run:
    docker run -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY my_app_name
```

i.e. the same! However, when executing

```bash
make run
```

python throws

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myfile.py", line 31, in <module>
    from my_module import (
  File "myfile.py", line 99, in <module>
    auth = AWSV4SignerAuth(credentials=credentials, region=region_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/opensearchpy/helpers/signer.py", line 55, in __init__
    raise ValueError("Credentials cannot be empty")
ValueError: Credentials cannot be empty
make: *** [run] Error 1
```

Why?

How do I fix it?

Comment: Are those environment variables actually set in the host environment?  Or are you getting credentials from somewhere else (`~/.aws/credentials`, the EC2 metadata service, OpenID Connect on EKS, ...)?

Comment: Weirdly, they are NOT set! But if I don't provide them to the direct `docker run` command, I get the same error. I only get success when those `-e` flags are set...!

Comment: When running locally, the only place they are defined is in `~/.aws/credentials` on the host. I can clarify the exact ECS setup if necessary - but if it works locally I am fairly sure it will work there too. On the other hand perhaps it works in the cloud but not locally...

Comment: You can bind-mount the AWS directory into the container. Assuming that you're running the container as root, it would be (iirc) `-v $HOME/.aws:/.aws`. But imo that's giving the container too many privileges, and it would be much better to expect people to set the environment variables.

Comment: Also, you should be passing `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION` along with the keys.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like it, and I would love to hear of a better way, but I ended up doing the following.

In the Makefile,

```bash
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$(shell aws configure get aws_access_key_id --profile default)
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$(shell aws configure get aws_secret_access_key --profile default)

run:
    #aws configure list # potentially useful
    #aws sts get-caller-identity # potentially useful
    docker run --platform linux/amd64 -e AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID -e AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY -i -t --rm --name= my_app_name $(APP_NAME)
```

Notes:

1. I tried to use `.ONESHELL` etc. but in vain.
2. I tried to use `&&` etc. but also in vain.
3. I didn't want to use a volume mount for the reasons given in the comments. I also didn't want the variables exported to all my other shells so I defined them solely within the Makefile (and hoped for the best :\ ).
4. I was right that the keys are automatically picked up on the deployed AWS side.